# Single entrypoint for pipeline steps in a docker image

Tags: docker, pipeline, entry-point

I have a docker image which encapsulates some processing steps: `A`, `B`, `C` with a linear dependency: `A -> B -> C`. Each step produces some artifacts (files) that will be required for subsequent steps.

What is a **robust** way of running this pipeline given these constraints?

---

A simple idea is to write a shell script, running each step like:

```
# run.sh

python step_a.py [args]
python step_b.py [args]
./step_c [args]
```

and define `run.sh` as the `ENTRYPOINT` of the docker image.

Would this be *good-enough*? What are some potential caveats? Is there a better approach?

I would have preferred something like `docker-compose`, but even with `depends_on`, it's not guaranteed that subsequent steps will run only after former steps are finished.

Comment: Would multi-stage builds be what you are looking for? Would be able to run a in stage 1, b in stage 2, and finally c in the final stage. Would use COPY to move only the files you need between stages; as I understand this should run in order. (I can make this a proper answer, but want to know if I am answering the right question)

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure what you mean by _stage_ -- like a CI/CD stage? I want a robust, non-ambiguous way of running this pipeline with the artifacts constraint. The "whole thing" is a single docker image.

Comment: Like stages within the docker file - [multi-stage](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) builds allow for you to break up a docker file into multiple stages, but still maintain a single file. It also allows docker to make the image smaller (sometimes also faster). If you give me a more concrete example of what you want to do, I can try and whip something up when I wake up.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. There's nothing inherently special about my steps. A and B are python scripts, while C is a rust binary. The flow is like this: `input -> A -> (a.foo) -> B -> (b.foo) -> C -> output`. `a.foo` and `b.foo` are required intermediate artifacts, but I only care about input and output files. I am mainly asking what the best practice would be in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most robust way to do this with a dockerfile would be to use [multi-stage](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) builds.

At its core, multi-stage builds just break up the docker file into multiple smaller images that you can control more granularly; so for your use case, you would have a stage for each part. Then you can copy the artifacts you need between stages. Finally, since you want an output and not a container, you would make the entry point the Rust binary and then have that spit out whatever you need. This would look a little something like this

```
FROM python-3.8:latest AS stage-1 // this can be whatever image you want

RUN pip install requirements_1.txt // install the reqs for the first python file

RUN python_file_1.py

FROM python-3.8:latest AS stage-2 // again, whatever image you want

RUN pip install requirements_2.txt // same idea

COPY --from=stage-1 ./artifact_1 ./destination // this copies the artifact from running python_file_1.py to somewhere you want it to be. The paths here are obviously placeholders

RUN python_file_2.py

FROM rust:1.31

COPY --from=stage-2 ./artifact_2 ./destination

ENTRYPOINT ["./rust_binary"]
```

Basic gist -

1. Make some python image, install prereqs for first python file
2. Run first python file
3. Makes some python image, install prereqs for second python file
4. Copy needed artifact from first stage to current (second) stage
5. Run second python file
6. Makes some rust image, install anything needed
7. Copy needed artifact from second stage to current (third) stage
8. Entrypoint into the rust binary, which should produce your output

Comment: Thank you! This does indeed look promising. Can I write 2 dockerfiles for this? A first one to completely build `my_image` with all its requirements, and a second one to be used as you described, so that I can do: `FROM my_image:latest as stage-N` and then `RUN cmd_for_stage_N` with `COPY` in between the stages.

Comment: Yes, as long as you build the first dockerfile into an image that ends up in your local registry (or you put it online somewhere), you can use it as the argument of `FROM`

Comment: This works. The only thing I need to set up now is copying input from host to docker and output from docker to host.

Comment: Awesome. Don't forget to accept an answer (if you consider the question answered)